# Trying to edit an article in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and think I am just missing something when it comes to modifying the values of an article, called appointment, in the database. I will list the relevant snippets of code.

I have an admin page set up that lists each of the users scheduled appointments, with an edit link next to each that takes me to the correct appointments/id#/edit page. The admin page in views:

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">All Scheduled Appointments</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <%@appointments.each do | appt |%>
            <%="Appointment for #{appt.owner_email} on #{appt.date} in the #{appt.time}"%> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_appointment_path(appt) %>
            </br>
          <%end%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The appointments_controller.rb file:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

The edit page that just contains options for the admin to select desired dates/times with a submit button. I wanted the admin selection of these values to update what the user had previously set them up to be. Hitting submit just refreshes the page though and seems to do nothing else. The edit.html.erb file in views:

```
<h1 align="center">Edit Existing Appointment</h1>

<form action="edit" method="refresh">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desiredDate">Desired Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="desiredDate" aria-describedby="desiredDate" placeholder="" name="desiredDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desiredTime">Desired Time</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="desiredTime" name="desiredTime">
          <option>Morning</option>
          <option>Afternoon</option>
          <option>Evening</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 text-center">
       <%= submit_tag "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My routes.rb code if that'd help:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'welcome#index'

  get '/services', to: 'welcome#services'
  get '/about_us', to: 'welcome#about_us'
  get '/schedule', to: 'welcome#schedule'
  get '/new_car', to: 'welcome#new_car'
  get '/my_profile', to: 'welcome#my_profile'
  get '/admin', to: 'welcome#admin'

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/sign_up', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  get '/appointments/edit', to: 'appointments#edit'
  resources :cars
  resources :appointments
end
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the Rails form helpers but have a hard-coded form?

Comment: My question is what am I missing that is preventing the "submit" button, once the Admin clicks on it, to edit/update the data/time values of the appointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first things first: why don't you use rails form helpers? You'll have your code cleaner and easier to debug.

That being said your form needs to point to proper controller method (`update` in your case). Anyways, I would try something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :desiredDate %>
          <%= f.date_field :desiredDate %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :desiredTime %>
          <%= f.select :desiredTime, ["Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening"], {}, class: "form-control"
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 text-center">
         <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've moved container outside of a form since it should be a wrapper to the edit page you do.

Comment: So your code is replacing the form in my edit page correct? But then how would I fix it to pointing to the proper controller method as you mention?

Comment: Yup, the code I've put already point proper record and should work fine. If you, however, want to keep your layout try with setting action to `"<%= appointment_path(params[:id]) %>"` (as @IlyaOsotov suggested)

Comment: Yea I just realized it went through to the update method as I got an error pointing me there. Silly question but, should this form helper be automatically sending the attributes we set here to the database and changing the appointment values or do I need to manually do that in the update method once it goes through? Thanks for your help with this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Nope, it won't save your data automatically. You should add a method for filtering parameters in the controller, and then those params should be used to update your appointment record. Check guides for tips: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html. 
If you find my answer helpful please mark it as a correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this: `<form action="edit" method="refresh">`. Change action to `"<%=appointment_path(params[:id])%>"` and method to "post".

Comment: Results in No route matches [POST] "/appointments/1".  When I run rake routes it shows edit_appointment GET /appointments/:id/edit appointments#edit